# Why isn't my game rendering properly?

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl

I am working on an engine with my friend, and something really odd is happening. I am confident that I have set everything up in LWJGL, and I am supposed to be rendering a grey rectangle in immediate mode, but it does not appear. We place it directly in from of the camera (it was representing the ground) but it still was not there. I am sure this is a question asked very much, but typing 'why isnt my opengl rendering' into google will get me thousands of results. So, I am going to show you a slimmed down version of its source code.

Here is the engines code: (extremely slimmed down)

```
 public class Engine {

private static int[] size = { 1200, 900 };
private static final DisplayMode DISPLAY_MODE = new DisplayMode(size[0], size[1]);

public static PhysicsHandler physicsHandler;
public static Thread physicsThread;

public static Canvas canvas;

public Engine() {

    loadGame();
    setUpDisplay();

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        render();
        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    cleanUp();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Engine();

}

private static void setUpDisplay() {

    try {

        Display.setDisplayMode(DISPLAY_MODE);
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
        Display.setTitle("Hello, world!");
        Display.create();   
        canvas = new Canvas();

    } catch (LWJGLException e) {

        System.err.println("Couldn't set up the display");
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(1);

    }

}

public void render() {

    canvas.render();

}

private static void cleanUp() {

    physicsThread = null;
    canvas.cleanUp();
    Display.destroy();

    }

}
```

Here is the canvas (aka the rendering code) :

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;
public class Canvas {

public void render(Vector3f pos, Vector3f rot) {

    //not used until I have a proper camera

}

public void render() {

    render3D();

}

public void clearGL() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glLoadIdentity();
}

public void init3D() {

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90, (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight(), 0.03f,20f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_FOG);

}

public void render3D() {
    glRotatef(5f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    init3D();
    clearGL();
    System.out.println("Trying to render");
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
     glColor4f(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1);
     glVertex4f(-50, 0, -50, 1);
     glColor4f(0.85f, 0.85f, 0.85f, 1);
     glVertex4f(-50, 0, +50, 1);
     glColor4f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.75f, 1);
     glVertex4f(+50, 0, +50, 1);
     glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
     glVertex4f(+50, 0, -50, 1);
     glEnd();

}

public static void cleanUp() {



}

}
```

Am I not setting up my states correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your perspective projection's far clipping plane is set to `20`, but your geometry ranges to `50`. The entire rectangle is way past the furthest point anything is allowed to be drawn at.

Also, you've got your axes mixed up for `glVertex4f`, assuming you want to draw a rectangle that isn't parallel to the direction you're looking in (which it is now). The 50s should be on the X and Y axes, and you should put in a value for Z that isn't 0 so that it's in front of the camera, not behind it.

Also, the first parameter of `gluPerspective` is *vertical* field of view, not horizontal, so you're going to get some serious distortion when you get it working. An approximate way to convert a 90 degree horizontal fov to a vertical one is to divide by the aspect ratio (`width / height`).

One other thing, that `glRotatef` call at the beginning of `render3D` isn't doing anything. `init3D` clears all transformations from the modelview matrix by calling `glLoadIdentity`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I fixed the problems I had wrong, but I am sorry to say that it is still not showing up. I am searching the web for more solutions, but will most likely scrap it and start again.

Comment: There's really very little code here to test, you shouldn't have to scrap it. Start with something that is definitely going to work: comment out the gluPerspective line, don't enable backface culling (this alone might be the issue depending on what winding order you've set/is default). Then change the vertices of the box to be inside NDC (that's [0, 1] on all 3 axes), and you should be able to see something.